# Why can’t I find a dual-link DVI *to* Displayport or HDMI adapter?

Tags: display, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, displayport

My situation is probably unique. I drive an older Mac Pro running Snow Leopard (OSX). It’s finicky about what video adapters will work (Not because of the hardware. Because Apple wants it that way.) Long story short — I have critical software that will only work on this OS, installed only on this computer, and the computer will only work with this (or one other) display adapter.

The problem: I need a new monitor, but the only output on my adapters are dual-link DVI ports. I use the full 2560x1600 resolution on both monitors.

All the new monitors only seem to have Displayport or HDMI inputs. My homie is too old to play that game.

I can find DP to DVI adapters all day, or bi-directional single-link DVI to DP/HDMI adapters, but *nowhere* can I find a Dual-Link DVI (computer side) **to** Displayport (monitor side).

I’m also not having any luck finding big bright monitors with DVI inputs.

Anyone got any products to recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Despite what the bot said, it's actually pretty clear what you're asking, but, it is also super clear in the site Help that this sort of question, questions asking for hardware or shopping recommendations, are specifically off topic.

Comment: Why? No target market.

Comment: ATI HD 5770 was available with DVI & 2xMini DP. You can pick them up on eBay for $£€ 30 or so, cheaper than 2 adapters. UK examples - https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p4432023.m570.l1313&_nkw=mac+ati+hd+5770&_sacat=0

Comment: BTW, 2560x1600 will be pretty rare these days, regular 2k 27" screens are 2560x1440 as standard.